# Sync SQLite with server database in real time

Tags: ios, reactjs, sqlite, react-native, real-time

I am creating my first app with React native.
This app let users interact to each other, for example with a chat.
I am using SQLite as local database, but I have no clear how can I implement then the real time part with the server, where all the other users data is stored.
I want to use messages and send notifications in real time, similar on how tinder does.
Any suggestion on where to start?